# Ansible Add parameters based on number of hosts

Tags: ansible

i have an requirement to pass paramaters to the node-id based on the number of hosts present in the host inventory

Considering we have 3 hosts , the parameter with node-is gets built as below
how can we achieve the same dynamically based on the host inventory ?

```
shell: init-cluster -cluster-name lbcluster -dbname {{ dbname }} -dbtype postgresql -dbhost {{ dbhost }} -dbport {{ dbport }} -dbuser {{ dbuser }} -dbpass {{ dbpass }} -zk-servers {{ zk-servers }} -storage-strategy {{ storage-strategy }} -storage-hdfs-uri hdfs://{{ hdfs-namenode }}:8020 -storage-hdfs-root /root -overwrite -node-id  host1 -node-id host2 -node-id host3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use "*set_fact*" and prepare the command. Start with the common variables

```
- set_fact:
    my_command: "init-cluster -cluster-name lbcluster -dbname {{ dbname }}
                 -dbtype postgresql -dbhost {{ dbhost }} -dbport {{ dbport }}
                 -dbuser {{ dbuser }} -dbpass {{ dbpass }} -zk-servers {{ zk-servers }}
                 -storage-strategy {{ storage-strategy }}
                 -storage-hdfs-uri hdfs://{{ hdfs-namenode }}:8020
                 -storage-hdfs-root /root
                 -overwrite"
```

and loop "*groups.all*" (fit the list to your needs).

```
- set_fact:
    my_command: "{{ my_command + ' -node-id ' + item }}"
  loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
- debug:
    var: my_command
- command: "{{ my_command }}"
```